# deleting a char pointer int a class makes console get stuck

Tags: c++

I tried implementing my own string class in for studying purposes, but I ran into a small problem.

I made a char pointer member in my String class (and heap allocated it in constructor). I also delete[] it in the deconstructor, and I noticed that the console gets stuck after trying to get out of the main method.

```
#include <iostream>
class String {
    char *str;
public:
    String() {}
    String(const char *s) {
        size_t len = strlen(s);
        str = new char[len];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
            str[i] = s[i];
        str[len] = '\0'; // null terminate
    }
    ~String() { delete[] str; }
};

int main() {
    String s("12");
} // <-- Program gets stuck here while trying to exit. Notice that when
  // I remove the delete[] in the deconstructor, the program runs fine.
```

The question is, why is this happenning? I dont get this error while trying to delete a normal char pointer, the following runs fine,

```
int main() {
    char *c = new char[2];
    delete[] c;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're writing outside the array bounds when you create the string, because you didn't allocate space for the null terminator. It should be:

```
str = new char[len + 1];
```

You also need to ensure that `str` is initialized by the default constructor:

```
String(): str(nullptr) {}
```

And make sure you follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and create a copy constructor.

Comment: Shot by duplet! XD

Comment: Also, your default `String()` constructor is not initializing the `str` pointer, so its value is garbage. You need to initialize `str` to NULL when not using it. Also, you are missing a copy constructor and copy assignment operator to make deep copies of the `str` data.

Comment: I was planning to add these in the future, but ye I admit that I forgot to initialize in the default constuctor...

Answer (score 4):

you allocate `len` characters

```
str = new char[len];
```

But `str[len]` is `len+1`-th character. You run out of bound and some kind of undefined behavior happens.

Answer (score 0):

this is because the array index starts from 0 up to the allocated size-1
for example str=new char[len] would be from str[0] up to str[len-1]
so, it should be str=new char[len+1];
it is the index out of bounds error